# javascript - check to see event was because of user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a centralized fn using $.ajax to send GETs to my API - this is called for 2 reasons 
- User clicked on something and I need to get the corresponding data or
- A setInterval is running that periodically polls for data.

In the beforeSend: handler, I want add a header if the request was because of the setInterval.

I've tried to use (new Error).stack, but it doesn't include the "setInterval" in the stack. The source of the other events seem to vary in the stack - so there's no single magic bullet to search for.

Is there a better way that looking for various strings in the stack to determine if the event was from a timer or user generated?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't look in the stack, I'd pass a parameter in from the click handler to indicate the click handler invoked it, if that doesn't exist then you would add the appropriate header

Comment: That's how I started attacking it. However, since there are multiple devs working on this project, I was hoping to make it a "framework" level operation - this way the other folks don't need to think about it going forward; Additionally, and tbh more onerously, the project already has *hundreds* of calls in place, so we'd have to go back an retro-fit the logic in many different places. Thanks